# Cannot declare a cursor on SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, cursor

I have an issue with using a cursor in queries on two different databases. When I execute following query on one of them it returns "1" which means that the cursor is defined and when I execute it on the second one it returns "-3" which means that the cursor has not been declared.

```
declare c1 cursor for select distinct P_ID from tbl_Select__1
open c1
SELECT CURSOR_STATUS('global','c1')
```

I am wondering whether I am missing something? Because the query on second database can declare the c1 and open that but still say that the status of the cursor is "-3" (has not been declared) and why it is working perfectly on the first one.

Comment: And you are using totally identical code against each database?

Answer (score 0):

Refresh SQL Server and check the connection are mapped to specific database.

- Step 1 : Connect to SQL Server
- Step 2 : Open DB1 in one session (say spid: 51)
- Step 3 : Open DB2 in another session (say spid: 52)

Now declare the same cursor in both sessions and compile.

It's working for me.